# JavaScript Loop returns unexpected result

Tags: javascript, scope, infinite-loop

Can anyone tell me why this logs `11`, instead of `9`?

```
function foo() {
  function bar(a) {         
    i =3;
    console.log( a + i );     
  } 

  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) { 
    bar( i *2 ); 
    //I know, infinite loop
  } 
} 

foo();
```

If `i` is hard-coded in `bar(){}`, shouldn't the logged result be 9?

This is part of a Scope class and I am lost.

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly something to do with `i` being used in *both* the `bar` function and in the `for` loop?

Comment: @Rocket, yup, missed the hoisting of `i` to the start of `foo()`.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it declaring var i =3; instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first iteration, `i` is `0` which is smaller than `10`. `0` (`2 * i`) is passed as `a` to `bar`. `i` gets set to `3`, then the sum is `3`.

In the next iteration, `i` is incremented to `4` (which is still smaller than `10`), then `8` (`2 * i`) is passed as `a` to `bar`. `i` gets reset to `3`, then the sum is `11`.

The next iteration is the same, `i` is incremented from `3` to `4` again and so on.

Your misunderstanding seems to be that the value of `a` doesn't change because `i` gets changed, the multiplication is evaluated first. Or you just missed the `i++` statement in the loop header.

Comment: I believe the part where he got stuck (and I can understand why) is because he thought `i` would _always_ be `3` from then on, indeed.

Comment: Yes, @Stephan, that's what I thought. Also, to fix the infinite loop I declared var i=3; instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi, that's it. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

@Bergi has the right answer, I just want to expand on it a bit. For primitive types like a string or number the parameter is passed by value. Here you are passing i into bar as the value a. Any changes to i or a will not effect the other's value. This also will not give you an infinite loop as the values for i in this case are [0, 4,5,6,7,8,9]

Now if i had been wrapped inside of an object that was passed to foo then you would have the problem you are asking about. Objects passed to javascript functions are passed by reference, so changes to the object in bar also happen in foo.